# Create an object from another object's group by key using lodash

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, lodash

For the given structure:

```
[{
    file: [{
        en: 'asset_string_en.jpg'
    }, {
        ch: 'assets_string_ch.jpg'
    }],

    assetName: 'assetName1'
}, {
    file: [{
        en: 'asset_string2_en.jpg'
    }, {
        ch: 'asset_string2_ch.jpg'
    }],

    assetName: 'assetName2'
}]
```

I want to make an object for each assetName with values grouped by these keys ['en', 'ch']:

```
{
'assetName1':'asset_string_en.jpg',
'assetName2':'asset_string2_en.jpg'
}

{
'assetName1':'asset_string_ch.jpg',
'assetName2':'asset_string2_ch.jpg'
}
```

How can I do this with lodash?

Comment: I suppose that `ru` is a typo in your second asset? Or do you want `ch` and  `ru` merged?

Comment: yeah it's a typo,  even so keys could be ['ru', 'ch','en']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could use some loops for creating the result set.

```js
var data = [{ file: [{ en: 'asset_string_en.jpg' }, { ch: 'assets_string_ch.jpg' }], assetName: 'assetName1' }, { file: [{ en: 'asset_string2_en.jpg' }, { ru: 'asset_string2_ch.jpg' }], assetName: 'assetName2' }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.file.forEach(function (b, i) {
        Object.keys(b).forEach(function (k) {
            result[i] = result[i] || {};
            result[i][a.assetName] = b[k];
        });
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using es6 fat arrow notation:

```
var arr = [{
    file: [{
        en: 'asset_string_en.jpg'
    }, {
        ch: 'assets_string_ch.jpg'
    }],

    assetName: 'assetName1'
}, {
    file: [{
        en: 'asset_string2_en.jpg'
    }, {
        ru: 'asset_string2_ch.jpg'
    }],

    assetName: 'assetName2'
}];

_.reduce(arr, (answer, obj)=> {answer[_.get(obj, 'file[0].en')] = _.get(arr[0], 'file[1].ch'); return answer}, {});
```